# NoMachine script to automatically lock the screensaver when disconnecting not working

Tags: bash, 16.04, nx

NoMachine provides [this resource](https://www.nomachine.com/AR12F00519) for adding a script to lock the system following a disconnect. However, this doesn't seem to work under any circumstances using any of the methods provided for any version of Ubuntu (I'm on 16.04).

The instructions also say to create a file called "`screen_lock.sh`" in `/usr/local/bin/` but then go on to reference adding "`UserScriptAfterSessionClose` `/usr/local/bin/lock_screen.sh`" to the configuration file.

Does anyone know if this is a typo or some unusual convention I'm unaware of? In any case, I've tried the using consistent file names with no success.

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo. The article now contains the right instructions.

1. Create a new file called `screen_lock.sh` in `/usr/local/bin/` containing the following:

   ```
   (script) content
   ```
2. Set permissions:

   ```
   chown root:root /usr/local/bin/screen_lock.sh
   chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/screen_lock.sh
   ```
3. Uncomment and modify the following key in `/usr/NX/etc/node.cfg`:

   ```
   UserScriptAfterSessionClose  "/usr/local/bin/screen_lock.sh"
   ```